# How to free resources of QString when use it inside std::vector

Tags: qt, c++11, vector

I have a structure "rs" for every record of my dataset.

All records are in a vector "r".

My record count is in “rc”.

```
.... 
struct rs{
  uint ip_i;//index
  QString ip_addr;//ip address
};
std::vector <rs> r;//rows ordered by key
int rc;//row count
....
```

I would like to control this memory usage.
That's why I don't want to use `r.insert` and `r.erase`.

When I need to insert a record, I will:

1. Increase size of r by `r.resize(..);r.shrink_to_fit()` (if needed).
2. Shift elements of r to the right (if needed) by `std::rotate`.
3. Put new values:  `r[i].ip_i=...;r[i].ip_addr=...`

When I need to delete a record, I will:

1. Shift elements of r to the left (if needed) by `std::rotate`.
   For example, `std::rotate(r.begin()+i,r.begin()+i+1,r.begin()+rc);`.
2. Free resources of `r[rc].ip_addr`.
   How to free resouces of QString `r[rc].ip_addr`?
   I've tried to do  `r[i].ip_addr.~QString()` and catched an runtime error.
3. Make `r.resize()` (if needed).

I don't want to loose memory because of Qstring copies stayed after rows deleting.

How can I control them?

Thanks.

Comment: `QString` is both reference counted and copy-on-write. So if there is no one else referencing it, it will be automatically freed. You should not even have to care about this, unless you are leaking memory somewhere else.

Comment: Am I right, that copy of QString will stay in memory till I decrease size of r below QString been placed?

Comment: *"Am I right"...* no

Comment: Why? How can I force QString to free resources if I don't need QString object inside `std::vector` anymore? Is it controllable? QString has a pointer to variable length data. Maybe, it will be enough just to set QString to ""?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QString` handles all memory control for you. Just treat it as a regular object and you'll be fine. `std::vector` is OO-aware, so it will call destructors when freeing elements.

The only thing you should *not* do is use low-level memory manipulation routines like `memcpy` or `memset`. `std::vector` operations are safe.

If you *really* want to free a string for a record that is within `[0..size-1]` range (that is, you do not actually decrease size with `resize()` after moving elements), then calling `r[i].ip_addr.clear()` would suffice. Or better yet, introduce the `clear()` method in your structure that will call `ip_addr.clear()` (in case you add more fields that need to be cleared). But you can only call it on a valid record, of course, not one beyond your actual vector size (no matter what the underlying capacity is, it's just an implementation detail).

On a side note, it probably makes sense to use `QList` instead since you're using Qt anyway, unless you have specific reasons to use `std::vector`. As far as memory control goes, `QList` offers `reserve` method which allows you reserve exactly as many elements as you need. Inserting then would look like

```
list.reserve(list.size() + 1);
list.insert(i, r);
```

Comment: I want to control `std::vector` `capacity()` size. That's why I use `resize()` with `shrink_to_fit()`. Of course, if I use `insert` and `erase` all will be correct with QString deleting. But I have to insert and delete rows without `insert` and `erase`.

Comment: As I've said, you're free to use any methods you want. `resize()` will call the destructors for you and free the memory for elements that are beyond the new size (no matter what the capacity is).

Comment: Ok. It is acceptable. So, I need to use decreasing r size `resize(..)` to free QStrings resources.

Comment: Right, or see my last edit for how to do it without changing size if you really need it (but I don't think it's a good style).

Comment: Thank you, but I use `std::vector` to speed up data record access and sorting. I have second vector `std::vector<int> i` as index of records in r. And QTableView uses vector "i" to display record data. It's hard for me to go to c++11 from assembler etc. I have to build a database program with short memory usage to port it for portable devices with low memory.

Comment: You're welcome, but please note that you *only* need it for “reachable” records. It doesn't make any sense to do `r[i].ip_addr.clear(); r.resize(i);` because `resize()` will free the memory anyway.